# Sum of square roots vs. square root of sum in summation notation

Tags: notation

Recently, a TA of mine wrote

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt x_i
$$

to represent the sum

$$
\sqrt {x_0 + x_1 + \cdots + x_{n-1} + x_n}.
$$

Is this an incorrect use of summation notation? My instinct is that the above sum is better represented by the following:

$$
\sqrt {\sum_{i=0}^n x_i}
$$

Which is correct?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: $\sqrt{9+16} = 5$ while $\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{16} = 7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt x_i=\sqrt {x_0} + \sqrt {x_1} + \cdots + \sqrt {x_n}
$$
But
$$
\sqrt {\sum_{i=0}^n x_i}=\sqrt {x_0 + x_1 + \cdots + x_n}
$$
which is different.